# What is the default root directory for webpack's devServer?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have Webpack already configured, with the following devServer configuration:

```
devServer:{
  port: 8080,
  host: 'localhost',
  publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  ...
}
```

how do I know where is the root directory for the dev server.
from the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase) of webpack, there is a setting `devServer.contentBase`, I don't have this set in my configuration.

> devServer.contentBase
>   (boolean string array)
>
> Tell the server where to serve content from. This is only necessary if you want to serve static files. devServer.publicPath will be used to determine where the bundles should be served from, and takes precedence.
>
> By default it will use your current working directory to serve content, but you can modify this to another directory:

I just don't understand how `devServer.publicPath` would tell the server where to serve content from!.

[Update]
I think that it serves files from the `output.path` setting in Webpack. but not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the below code , if you see the `publicPath: '/'` means it will take the directory where the `webpack.config.js` is present.

```
  devServer: {
            open: 'http://localhost:9000',
            port: 9000,
            publicPath: "/",
        },
```

if you want to specify the folder , you need to pass the folder name  like below.

```
 devServer: {
                open: 'http://localhost:9000',
                port: 9000,
                publicPath: "/foldername",
            },
```

Comment: I needed to provide `publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/'` in order for Hot Module Replacement (HMR) to work properly.

Comment: @osama7901 , you check the link https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/,  it might help , especially check the `devServer` and `plugin` part